# Request for an article by Jim Lawrence

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

Jim Lawrence has a very important paper on the topic of valuations on polyhedra called  "*Rational-function-valued valuations on polyhedra*", published in the DIMACS volume *Discrete and computational geometry* of the AMS.

**Does anyone have a scanned copy of this article that can be shared?**

Google books has a preview of almost all the article, except for section 5 an the references, which are the ones that I mostly need. I wrote to Jim Lawrence asking him if he has a copy, but he told me that he surely has a copy in his office, but for obvious reasons (a global pandemic, in case someone reads this in a 100 more years) he is working from home (like the most of us).

PS: I obviously looked already at those sites which start with *lib* and *sci*, without success.

Comment: If you're affiliated with a university, your librarian can almost surely arrange this for you, with appropriate precautions against copyright infringement.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm a 100% sure that the librarian from my university isn't able nor capable of doing that task.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  The physical book seems to be held by at least some university libraries, so I would have thought you could get it by interlibrary loan.

Comment: @NateEldredge That works well in the US, but not necessarily in other countries and we have no clue about the location of the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a scan of the chapter and can email it, just let me know the address.

The reference list (missing from the Google books preview) is here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, as always, Carlo. My email is e_finat (at) yahoo (dot) com